# Pandas: Replace value in column by using another column, if condition is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Sector_x': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],  'Sector_y': ['abc', '', '', 'xyz']})
```

I would like to replace value in column Sector_y by using column Sector_x, if Sector_y = ''

so that I get the following result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Sector_x': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],  'Sector_y': ['abc', 'test2', 'test3', 'xyz']})
```

I tried using the code

```
df['Sector_y'] = np.where('',['Sector_x'],['Sector_y'])
```

but didn't deliver the result I wanted.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: your syntax is off: `df['Sector_y'] = np.where(df['Sector_y'] == '',df['Sector_x'],df['Sector_y'])`. Also, generally speaking you should always have the dataframe in front of the column name -- otherwise you are passing a list with one string instead of a dataframe series. Obviously, if a pandas method, expects a list of column names like in `groupby`, then this syntax works, but `np.where` takes: 1. a conditional series and either a series or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix `np.where`

```
df['Sector_y'] = np.where(df['Sector_y'] =='', df['Sector_x'], df['Sector_y'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.loc` to specify the filtering condition and specify the target column `Sector_y` and assign with values from column `Sector_x`, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Sector_y'] =='', 'Sector_y'] = df['Sector_x']
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

     ISIN       Name Sector_x Sector_y
0  A1kT23  Example A    test1      abc
1    4523    Name Xy    test2    test2
2    B333  Example B    test3    test3
3   49O33    Test123    test4      xyz
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use `apply` row-wise, and simply compare string across columns using the `or` operator (taking advantage from the fact that empty strings evaluate to `False`):

```
df['Sector_y'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Sector_y'] or row['Sector_x'], axis=1)
```

output:

```
     ISIN       Name Sector_x Sector_y
0  A1kT23  Example A    test1      abc
1    4523    Name Xy    test2    test2
2    B333  Example B    test3    test3
3   49O33    Test123    test4      xyz
```